# add class for selected radio button in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf. I am trying to add a class based on the selected radio button in a for loop.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div th:remove="tag" th:each="obj : ${T(com.sab2i.esabplugin.model.NatureEnum).values()}" >
        <label class="btn btn-primary" th:classappend ="...?'active'">
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"  th:field="*{nature}"  th:value="${obj}" />
            <span th:text="#{${obj.value}}">Radio</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

what test should I be making to compare the value of "nature" against the value of loop variable "obj", in order to add the "active" class in **th:classappend**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try `th:classappend="(${obj} eq *{nature})? 'active'"`

if `*{nature}` is a `String` try `th:classappend="(${obj.name()} eq *{nature})? 'active'"`

Comment: hi, your first provided solution did not work, however the 2nd one did. I think the main problem is that i was comparing using the "==" sign and not "eq".